# Attempting to make a Pythagorean theorem code but its not working as planned

Tags: java, math

When I put in my height and base of a triangle, I get NaN. For example in the code below, I have "hi" as height, b as "base" and h as "hypotenuse", if I enter 1 for base and 1 for height I get NaN for the hypotenuse. How I have it is that if one of the sides are unknown, then the user will set it as 0, but it's for some reason not working. I was wondering if there is a mistake in my code?

Note: c as seen in c.nextDouble() is the scanner name.

```
double h = 0, b = 0, hi = 0;

System.out.println("Please enter in the sides as asked, if the unknown side is asked, then enter it as 0");

System.out.println("Enter the height of the triangle:");
hi = c.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter the base of the triangle: ");
b = c.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter the hypotenuse of the triangle: ");
h = c.nextDouble();

if (h != 0) {
    h = Math.sqrt((b * b) + (hi * hi));

    System.out.println("The hypotenuse side is:" + h);

} else if (hi != 0) {
    hi = Math.sqrt((h * h) - (b * b));

    System.out.println("The height is: " + hi);

} else if (b != 0) {
    b = Math.sqrt((h * h) - (hi * hi));

    System.out.println("The height is: " + b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your if statements aren't correct. You had the logic go "if h doesn't equal 0, set it b^2 - hi^2." That doesn't really make sense because they would mean one of those values would be zero as well.

also, your input is a little off. Java gets weird when you dont accept the \n from pressing enter. just add c.nextLine(); after every c.nextDouble()

example input grab:

```
h = c.nextDouble();
c.nextLine(); //there is no need to store it anywhere.
```

logic fix:

```
if (h == 0) {
    h = Math.sqrt((b * b) + (hi * hi));

    System.out.println("The hypotenuse side is:" + h);

} else if (hi == 0) {
    hi = Math.sqrt((h * h) - (b * b));

    System.out.println("The height is: " + hi);

} else if (b == 0) {
    b = Math.sqrt((h * h) - (hi * hi));

    System.out.println("The height is: " + b);
}
```

}

Comment: NextLine() is the only function that accepts and handles the endline